# Connecting to mongo database through SSH tunnel in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, ssh

We have our MongoDB setup on AWS which can only be access via SSH over the VPC. In our VPC we have a public server running PHP, now i want to try connecting the PHP to the MongoClient but i always get following error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with
>   message 'Failed to connect to: :27017: Connection timed
>   out' in /var/www/html/app/getDetails.php:34 Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/app/getDetails.php(34):
>   MongoClient->__construct('mongodb://

I can't get any solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you Database is in private subnet you need to configure security group as follows

Add private IP of Application instance to Security group of Database instance with ALL ICMP and Custom TCP with desired port number.

To check if Application instance is able to connect Database instance

`telnet` `Database Private IP` `Port Number`

Answer (score 0):

Got this working, in my Application instance i just need to allow that port to connect to my Database private ip.

@niteshd22 : Thanks for your effort mate.